# Where to put user uploaded files in play framework?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

There is the possibility in my web App that the user can upload different files. the files are not stored in the DB, but in the file System. but I don't want them to be accessible publicly (only throw my Controller). is there any difference between storing the files in the `/public` folder  or can i also make another folder in the root of my play app and put the files inside?

does play see them in the same way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should keep uploaded files apart the application structure at all, so just create dedicated directory in the file system and store uploaded files in it.

TIP: you can (should?) add custom directive to `application.conf` so you won't need to hardcode the path into your controller and will be able to change upload dir per instance by manipulating the config files. i.e.:

**application.conf**:

```
myUploadDir = "/home/behzad/upload/dir/"
```

**your action**:

```
String uploadDir = Play.application().configuration().getString("myUploadDir");
```

Comment: which directive I had to use?